# Get Site Collection full URL using javascript

Tags: development, javascript, client-object-model

I want to get the URL for my site collection. One way I thought I could do it was using the window.location in javascript and getting it that way.

I know that you can use ECMA script and the client object model to do this but unsure how.

I have tried:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext;
alert(context.get_url());
```

This is returning `/`

How would I get it to include the full URL? i.e. `http://mysharepoint:29292/`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can do it without any SharePoint calls by using the default JavaScript location object ([W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp)) and the page variable `_spPageContextInfo` ([Ted Pattison's Blog](http://blog.tedpattison.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=9)).

Something like:

```js
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
```

Comment: In my experience despite that this approach will work in a production environment, if you have a large team and you don't control their development environment @Matthias approach is better because it will work even when a developer is working with localhost. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24817/get-site-collection-full-url-using-javascript/24818#24818

Comment: +1 for Exact Solution

Comment: Great solution. Although I also needed the path to the current web which your solution didn't really take it all the way. But _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl held what I was looking for.

Comment: This wont work in 2007 will it?

Answer (score 14):

You can do it like this:

```
<script>
function GetSiteUrl()
  {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
    var site = ctx.get_site();
    ctx.load(site);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(s, a){alert(site.get_url())});
  }
</script>
<a href='javascript:GetSiteUrl();'>Get site URL</a>
```

To load only the URL from the site to minimize data traffic you can also call:

```
ctx.load(site, 'Url');
```

For more see reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538253.aspx

Comment: var siteUrl = site.get_url(); throws a SP.Res.propertyHasNotBeenInitialized exeception

Comment: I have updated the sample..., it works now.

Comment: Just for John - the difference between normal SP object model programming and the Client object model is that nothing actually happens until ctx.executeQueryAsync - so in previous example you were asking for site properties while it was still 'null' (not strictly null but you get the idea)

Comment: I had to add this code to Mattias' answer to get this all working: // Call function InitSiteUrl() after SP resources are loaded ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(InitSiteUrl, 'sp.js');

Answer (score 13):

You can do it in Singleline of code

```
var siteCollectionURL = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
```

Comment: This is correct for SharePoint 2013, SP2010 _spPageContextInfo does not have the property siteAbsoluteUrl.

Answer (score 3):

```
function initialize()
    {
       var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       siteCollec = clientContext.get_site();
       clientContext.load(siteCollec);
       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, getUrl), Function.createDelegate(this, getFailed));
     }


function getUrl()
    {
       alert(site.get_url());
    }
    function getFailed()
    {
       alert('Failed to retrieve the server relative URL.');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use any of the two:

```
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
```

Or we can use

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext();
var relativeWebUrl = context.get_url();
var fullWebUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + relativeWebUrl ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

For Site Collection URL:

```
var url = window.location.protocol + “//” + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
```

For Sub Site URL:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to find WebApp url, this takes care of port number too (if exists)

```
var WebAppUrl="";
if (location.port)
    {
        WebAppUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + ":" + location.port;
    }
    else
    {
        WebAppUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add another answer here as we've come into the age of the Sharepoint Add-In model and this won't work if you want to get the top level site collection from an Add-In, since you'll either be using a Provider Hosted add-in where your page is hosted off-site or Sharepoint Hosted add-in where it's hosted in the Add-In web.  These answers will give you the URL for the Add-In web.

I got the top level site collection url from my Sharepoint Hosted add-in by using the following code:

```
//Get the URI decoded URLs.
hostweburl =
    decodeURIComponent(
        getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
);
// Set toplevelurl to the top level site collection url
toplevelurl = hostweburl.split("://")[0] + "://" + hostweburl.split("://")[1].split('/')[0];
```

Of course if you actually want to take any actions on the top level site collection, remember to use the Cross Domain Library, specifically `SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory` and `SP.AppContextSite` so something like:

```
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(addinweburl);
var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(addinweburl);
clientContext.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
topContext = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, toplevelurl);
```

I won't go into using the CDL as that's covered well elsewhere and it's way beyond the scope of this question.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery, no spContext.  This can be used on a modern site.  Probably needs some tweaking but the idea is to do it using a regex rather than any SharePoint or library provided object.

https://jsfiddle.net/4kz1wt3d/

```
function getSiteRelativeUrl(urlString) {
  var expr = "/sites/[A-Za-z0-9-]*"

  var match = urlString.match(expr);

  return match;
}

function getSiteAbsoluteUrl(urlString) {
  var expr = "https://[a-zA-Z.0-9]*"

  var matchFirstPart = urlString.match(expr);
  var relativeUrl = getSiteRelativeUrl(urlString);

    var ret = matchFirstPart + relativeUrl;

  return ret;
}

var url = "https://mySharePointSite.sharepoint.com/sites/WithumTest-022/sitepages/somepage.aspx"

var relativeUrl = getSiteRelativeUrl(url);
var absoluteUrl = getSiteAbsoluteUrl(url);

console.log(relativeUrl[0]);
console.log(absoluteUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Site URL : _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl
e.g. "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/site1"

Page URL window.location.href
e.g. "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/SitePages/Home.aspx"

Answer (score -1):

```
<script language="javascript">
            _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("GrabUrl");
            function GrabUrl()
            {
                // Custom JavaScript methods
                var currentUrl = document.URL;
                alert(currentUrl);
</script>
```