# Possible to load sitecollection without direct reference

Tags: client-object-model

I've followed one of the tutorials to use CSOM (JavaScript) to work on a list. I need to template the site and create new sites from it.

But in my code (CEWP and txt file) I have a hard coded link. Is it somehow possible to change to grab site collection (itdevSC) ?

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/itdevSC/mysubsite';     
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
```

Comment: You mean current site collection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Site Collection full URL using javascript](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24817/get-site-collection-full-url-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the URL using

```
var siteUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
```

Comment: Or directly use `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl` instead of concatenating protocol and host info from `window.location`