# Get SharePoint URL using sp-pnp-js in SPFx

Tags: javascript, spfx, pnp, react, pnpjs

I have a SharePoint SPFx react webapp that I'm working on. I'm trying to get the SharePoint URL. For example:

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/SitePages/Home.aspx#/
```

So I want to get `https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename`

I've tried using references from here:
[Get Site Collection full URL using javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24817/get-site-collection-full-url-using-javascript) and [spfx-how-use-site-url-from-current-page-context-in-react-spfx-solution](https://www.nehachandil.com/post/spfx-how-use-site-url-from-current-page-context-in-react-spfx-solution)

The issue I'm having is I'm using the older `sp-pnp-js` library so all the examples I found online reference the newer pnpJS library.

So `this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl` and `spHttpClient` do not work with the older `sp-pnp-js` library

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl` with the older `sp-pnp-js` library.

I have used something similar to below and it works in our tenant.

```
import { sp, Web } from 'sp-pnp-js';
const web = new Web(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);
web.lists.getByTitle('list name').items.getById(1250).select('Title').get();
```

Comment: When I used that, I get a `'context' is deprecated` error and the page fails. did this in my `componentDidMount` and then `console.log(web)`

Comment: How are you passing the content object to the component being rendered, i do something similar to this. `const element: React.ReactElement<IFormProps > = React.createElement( Form, { context: this.context } )`

Comment: Also if you are using the old interface `IWebPartContext` that would be why you are getting that error as it is deprecated. There is a newer interface `WebPartContext`. In my case my webpart props looks like this `export interface IFormWebPartProps { description: string; listName: string; context: WebPartContext; }`